# IHTMLDocument2 does not work everywhere

Tags: c#, ihtmldocument2

In a winform application I have `WebBrowser` control and a `PictureBox`. I am loading an Image (from webbrowser control after `DocumentComplete`) to pictureBox1 with the code below

```
IHTMLDocument2 doc = (IHTMLDocument2)webBrowser1.Document.DomDocument;
IHTMLControlRange imgRange = (IHTMLControlRange)((HTMLBody)doc.body).createControlRange();

foreach (IHTMLImgElement img in doc.images)
    {

         imgRange.add((IHTMLControlElement)img);

         imgRange.execCommand("Copy", false, null);

         pictureBox1.Bitmap = (Bitmap)Clipboard.GetDataObject().GetData(DataFormats.Bitmap);

     }
```

Image is displayed in picturebox1 on my pc, but not on my friend's. On another windows XP it worked well after installing VS2008. So I guess IHTMLDocument2 needs a windows update to work correctly.

Which update is that? Or any other alternative to this code in which i don't have to redownload image from internet?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you need to deploy additional files (dlls?) available [Here.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/249232)

The best option (and what most people do) is to use something like [System.Net.WebClient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to download the source, and the use WebClient again to download the image.

If you are determined to use an interface for HTML `IHTMLDocument2` the file that contains this interface is in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft.NET\Primary Interop Assemblies\Microsoft.mshtml.dll`   (without the x86 if you are running 32-bit Windows).  Include this file in your project if you are using a VS Deployment project (or copy it to the running application directory manually).

Comment: I am unable to find any dlls on the link.

Comment: are you talking about http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?DisplayLang=en&id=21596 ?